# How to make a custom class which inherits from Sklearn's RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'd like to take a regression algorithm from sklearn, let's say  a RandomForestRegressor:

```
from sklearn import ensemble

clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=None)

class model(clf):
    def __init__(self):
        clf.__init__(self)

    def inSampleAccuracy(self):
        print('\"accuracy is calculated\"')

testModel = model()
```

I get a warning:

```
FutureWarning: Pass criterion=(RandomForestRegressor(),), max_depth={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'model', '__init__': <function model.__init__ at 0x7f2304dd67b8>, 'inSampleAccuracy': <function model.inSampleAccuracy at 0x7f2304d6d6a8>} as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
  "will result in an error", FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

And an error at line 12, the last line.

```
TypeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object is not callable
```

I've tried a couple variations on this:

```
from sklearn import ensemble

clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=None)

class model(clf):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

    def inSampleAccuracy(self):
        print('\"accuracy is calculated\"')

testModel = model()
```

And this simpler instance

```
from sklearn import ensemble

clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=None)

class model(clf):

    def inSampleAccuracy(self):
        print('\"accuracy is calculated\"')

testModel = model()
```

The error is the same in these two other cases.

I'm not certain whether this is because I do not understand inheritance or because I do not understand sklearn adequately.

My motivation was fairly simple, I figured it would be neat to have a regression tool with all the functionality offered by sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor and have some extra methods and encapsulated data unique to the particular problem I'm attempting to solve

Comment: This is not how you inherit from a class in python, you need to inherit directly from RandomForestRegressor, not an instance of it.

Comment: What you are trying to inherit from **is not a class**: `class model(clf)`, where `clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=None)`. That is, `clf` is **not a class**.

Comment: So, `ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` is a class. `ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=None)` calls that class, and gives you an instance of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I shortened the question to the RandomForestRegressor example as you suggested. I'd accept further rebuking, but I think the last paragraph in this edit summarizes the desired answer adequately

Answer (score 0):

As @Dr. Snoopy and @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, I fallaciously attempted to to inherit from an instance of an object from a class in the examples given in my question.

The syntax for inheritance from a python module object looks more like this:

```
from sklearn import ensemble

clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor

class model(clf):    
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
```

In my case, where I'd like to keep most of the inherited classes functionality, I can add the object parameters into this new class. Like this:

```
from sklearn import ensemble

clf = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor

class model(clf):    
    def __init__(self, max_depth):
      super().__init__()
      self.max_depth = max_depth
  
    def inSampleAccuracy(self):
        print('\"accuracy is calculated\"')


myModel = model(max_depth=1000)
print(myModel.get_params())
myModel.inSampleAccuracy()
```

Output:

{'max_depth': 1000}
"accuracy is calculated"

It seems the resulting object is behaving as intended (I'll experiment with this object in the main body of code, if it's not quite right, I'll be back here fairly quickly), but this approach seems a little crude to me. I'm betting there is a way to stipulate that all attributes needed to create an instance of the inherited class can be defined when an object instance is written. Explicitly writing out which parameter I wish to alter when making an instance of the object seems a little plodding.

But thanks for the comments, this seems like a cool way to use classes from python libraries.